# Added TableView to Sprite is not visible and all other Sprites are visible

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I inherited Sprite and I want to put inside TableView but when I add inherited Sprite to scene table is not visible but all others sprites added to inherited sprite are visible ( I checked it creates cells, position and z index are set right, when I add TableView directly to Scene it is visible).

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to add a TableView to a Sprite in Cocos2d-x v3.6, but it's a little hard to say exactly why yours isn't showing up. Here are some things to check:

- Have you added the TableView as a child to the Sprite via `addChild`?
- When you add the TableView to the Sprite, is your DataSource set properly? (This seems to be the case given your question).
- Are there positioning issues when you add it to the Sprite due to the anchor position(s) of your Sprite and it's parent(s)? It could be the TableView with incorrect positioning, or it could be the TableViewCells themselves. Remember that when you add a child to some Node, its anchor point is `Vec2(0.5, 0.5)`.
- You're not forced to override `cocos2d::Size cellSizeForTable(cocos2d::extension::TableView *table)`, and if you don't have cell heights, the cells might not show up.
- Try "dumbing down" any logistics you have and follow the code in TableViewTestScene.cpp, which is part of the cpp-tests. (cocos-directory/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/ExtensionsTest/TableViewTest)
- Last resort: Try doing something silly like giving your table and cells a large height and width of 500-1000 pixels each. Give them an absolute position somewhere in your Sprite. Give each of them a Label that says "Hello, World!" and see if they show up.

It might be helpful to see your applicable code, too.

A very late edit: I realized today that it seems as though Layer objects (and thus TableViews) always have an Anchor Point of `Vec2::ANCHOR_BOTTOM_LEFT`. Could this be your issue?